# Как в SonataAdmin один Admin запихнуть в tab другого без возможности редактирования?

Tags: symfony, symfony3, sonata

Здравствуйте.
Есть два Admin. Хочу, чтобы один Admin отображался с помощью configureListFields в **табе** другого Admin/

Сейчас сделал вот так.

```
$formMapper
        ->tab('Admin 2')
        ->add('someProperty', 'sonata_type_collection', [
            'required' => false,
        ],
            [
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
            ])
        ->end()
        ->end();
```

Все отображается, но с помощью configureFormFields.
То-есть колонки сразу готовы к редактированию, а надо просто чтобы была таблица как ее рисует configureListFields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sonata_type_collection` - это алиас для класса [`Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType`](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/blob/3.x/Form/Type/CollectionType.php), - это Form Type, т.е. поле формы. Поэтому есть 2 варианта: сделать новый Form Type со схожим функционалом, либо сделать кастомный шаблон для вывода поля.

Ещё если добавить `'disabled' => true` в массив третьего параметра функции `add`, то будет нельзя редактировать значения в таблице для `someProperty`. Но всё равно колонки будут взяты из `configureFormFields`.